# Azure Notification Hub Unauthorized Exception

Tags: azure-notificationhub, azure-android-sdk

After tracing the link below, my dummy Android application always got an unauthorized notification hub exception

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/

What could be the reason for this error?,

Comment: Can you check whether the expiry in the SAS key is correct for Turkish? What does `generateSasToken()` return for Turkish and what does it return for English? Maybe the number formatting is different and you don't get the correct expiry value in the SAS string for Turkish...

Comment: I think you are right. But we are using Notification Hub Android Sdk. Microsoft should resolve the issue. Do you have any other solution that i can resolve myself

Comment: I have found and fixed the problem by changing notification-hubs-0.4.jar file. In connection.java, there is a method namely generateAuthToken, and if you change the code 

url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

to

url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

jar file works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your phone's date and time are the same as Azure's. Or just use automatic time and date settings.

Comment: As seen in the link below, this was a bug of Azure Notification Hub [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fd26e66-d9b8-43a0-92ac-65f75bb559bb/my-android-application-got-an-unauthorized401-exception-in-production-environment?forum=notificationhubs)

Comment: This fixed my problem. Sometimes the time of the android emulator is wrong and this was causing the problem in my case. Restarting the emulator fixed the time and thus the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that your hub name and connection string were filled in within the Android Application? You should have values for the lines:

```
private String HubName = "<Enter Your Hub Name>";
private String HubListenConnectionString = "<Your default listen connection string>";
```

Just a guess given the details provided

Comment: System works in android emulator correctly. That make me sure about hubname and connection string